# Is there a word like ‘genocide’, but for a specific family?

Tags: single-word-requests

I swear I read such a word once, as does my partner; but no amount of Googling has been able to suss it out:

I’m looking for something that means “to extinguish a family tree,” in the sense of complete genetic extinction; to hunt down and kill all members of someone’s extended family.

(Dark, I know!)

Answer (score 1):

'**Familicide**' is the killing of an entire family.

> A familicide is a type of murder or murder-suicide in which a perpetrator kills multiple close family members in quick succession,

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familicide)

> Entire Family Killed, Allegedly Becoming Victims of **Familicide** in Tangerang

[NetrainNews - 13th Feb 2018](http://www.en.netralnews.com/news/currentnews/read/18379/entire.family.allegedly.becomes.victims.of.familicide.in.tangerang)

'Fratricide' is the killing of siblings; 'matricide' the killing of a mother; and 'patricide' the killing of a father.